# Is it possible to send "resize pty" command with telnetlib?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I am looking for a way to resize terminal when using `telnetlib`. I have achieved a similar effect on SSH with Paramiko's [resize_pty](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#resize_pty), but I need to support telnet protocol too. Is this even possible (does telnet even have a control stream)?

Note that telnetlib is not a requirement - if there is a better library I would be happy to use it.

**UPDATE** (more background): I am building a web-based interface for connecting to networking devices. Frontend is built using JS/AJAX, it basically just sends keystrokes to backend and receives screen content from it. Backend is written in Python and takes care of opening a SSH/telnet session to a device, sends keystrokes to it and fetches an output stream, which is then passed through VT100 virtual terminal ([pyte](https://github.com/selectel/pyte)). The contents of virtual screen are then sent back to frontend. The problem arises when user wants to resize the terminal screen size in his browser. With SSH I just send `resize_pty()` through Paramiko and then also resize the pyte's virtual terminal screen size. But with telnet I was unable to find the appropriate resize function that would tell the device that it should resize its terminal. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what are you doing? Do you need telnetlib to handle some kind of pseudo-terminal with server output for you, or just send the resize terminal request to it?

Comment: @MichałGórny: I have updated the question, I hope it makes more sense now... :)

Comment: Thanks. I've did a bit of research and when the terminal is resized, telnetd debugs `td: recv suboption NAWS 0 97 (97) 0 26 (26)`. Sadly, I don't see any specific option in `telnetlib` to send suboptions but I'll have to take a closer look at the protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've been able to assemble the following masterpiece:

```
naws_command = struct.pack('!BBBHHBB',
        255, 250, 31, # IAC SB NAWS
        width, height,
        255, 240) # IAC SE
t.get_socket().send(naws_command)
```

Now a few words of explanation.

First of all, `telnetlib` does not support sending commands directly; it simply escapes them. Thus, to send the command we have to use the underlying socket directly. We do that using the `get_socket()` method of the `Telnet` object instance (`t` here).

The `NAWS` command assembled here is defined by [RFC 1073](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1073.txt). The `width` and `height` variables are regular Python integers which get packed into two 16-bit unsigned integers.

Note that this isn't a perfect solution and I'm not sure if it will actually work for you. Most importantly, during the capabilities negotiation, `telnetlib` will inform the server that it `WON'T NAWS`, so a particular server may actually ignore the commands.

If that's the case, you'd probably have to use [set_option_negotiation_callback()](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.set_option_negotiation_callback). Sadly, that means you will have to handle all the options which normally `telnetlib` does for you. And AFAIK it has no conveniences for that.

Comment: Thank you!!! I had to use `set_option_negotiation_callback()` to set `WILL NAWS` exactly as you described. It wasn't that much work either, I just studied telnetlib.py and replicated its handling of messages - just a few lines. It works perfectly now. :)

Comment: Yes, the `telnetlib` seems pretty straightforward in code. And it has a few symbolic constants you could use as well; but I think you'd need to replace `B` with `c` in the `pack()` call.